# List of files that control logging and the corresponding log files OSX

Tags: macos, logging

The title should be clear. However, some logging done by `syslogd` can be controlled using `asl.conf`.

Where can I find a list of files that control all the other log files that come as standard? (not asking for 3rd party, but appreciated as well)

Using OS 10.10.4 Yosemite (but hardly any difference between named versions)
e.g.

```
/private/var/log/accountpolicy.log
/private/var/log/authd.log
/private/var/log/commerce.log
/private/var/log/coreduetd.log
/private/var/log/displaypolicyd.log
/private/var/log/fsck_hfs.log
/private/var/log/install.log
/private/var/log/opendirectoryd.log
/private/var/log/secinitd.log
/private/var/log/wifi.log
```

and what is with the ones found in `~/user/Anon/Library/Logs` such as:

```
talagent.log
DiskUtility.log
```

and of course the folder specific ones like mail, iTunes and so forth.

I would like to control them all but first I need to know who writes them on which criteria and where can I manipulate them, preferably one by one since just killing demons seems not the way to go.

Comment: Not even apple does this in the manpages.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not require its software engineers to be consistent in how logs are enabled, how logging levels are adjusted, where logs are written, and whether or where these things are documented. Nor does it impose such rules on the various open source packages that make up much of the Darwin/Unix layer of OS X.

I doubt anyone has a good list, and any such list would have to change significantly in each major OS release to keep up to date.

Comment: so the best solution is still to run a daemon  issuing: "sudo find / name "*.log.*" -delete"  At least for the OSX processes there must be a better solution. I worked trough the results of such a list (without del) and most are only vaguely described by apple regarding from where they are coming from.

Comment: wont print asterisks for me in the bash code